# Zend PDF write html code to instead text

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-pdf, pdf-conversion

I have success to test my code with function `Zend_Pdf()` for easy to understand, this is my code :

```
    $pdf = new Zend_Pdf();
    $page = new Zend_Pdf_Page(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
    $font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA);
    // set font for page
    // write text to page
        $test = "This is reporting for <br /> hello world: LALALA......";
    $page->setFont($font, 15)
        ->drawText('That which we call a rose,', 72,720)
        ->drawText("$test", 72, 620);
    // add page to document
    $pdf->pages[] = $page;
    $pdf->save("data/reports/" . $_SESSION['User_fonction'] ."-report.pdf");
```

My cods will show in pdf file

```
That which we call a rose
```

and   `This is reporting for <br /> hello world: LALALA......`

My question

how i can resolve this problem by i can write tag html in it by well like tag `<br />`  is should know ? 
any one used to understand on it please. Any help ...

I am looking forword to see your reply soon. thanks .

Comment: there is no indication in the documentation that `Zend_Pdf_Page` supports html2pdf conversion

Answer (score 2):

What you want to achieve is you have html (so text with markup) and that must be converted into a PDF file. This is unfortunately not the goal of Zend_Pdf. The pdf component allows only to set plain text and not any markup attached.

You can use a Zend Framework 2 module (you tagged your question with zend-framework-2, I assume you use it then) called [DomPdfModule](https://github.com/raykolbe/DOMPDFModule). You use Zend Framework 2 view scripts to render the result and use above module to convert it into a PDF file.

Comment: thanks for this info, it's a good solution but i can't up-grand full of my project by this point. but any way i will chose it for my second project

Answer (score 1):

Zend_PDF won't handle HTML, you should try something such as:

```
http://www.tcpdf.org/

http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/
```

Comment: my point as pointed out above is that Zend_PDF won't handle writing of HTML inside PDF documents, it's not meant for that kind of usage. You should try a library made specifically for that reason, such as the ones pointed out